# find the minimum of the values $\sum ij\cos{(x_{i}-x_{j})}$

Tags: inequality, optimization

Fix a positive integer $n$. Out of all possible $0\le x_{1}\le x_{2}\le\cdots\le x_{n}\le \pi$, find the minimum of the value of
$$F=\sum_{1\le i<j\le n}ij\cos{(x_{i}-x_{j})}$$

I have try since
$$2F=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\sin{x_{i}})^2+(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cos{x_{i}})^2-\sum_{i=1}^{n}i^2$$

Comment: The first sums in the expression for $2F$ can be joined to produce
$$
2F = \left| \sum_{k=1}^n k e^{i kx_k}\right|^2 - \sum k^2,
$$
which might be helpful.

Comment: it's same as me.because $|\sum_{k=1}^{n}ke^{ikx_{k}}|^2=(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\sin{x_{i}})^2+(\sum_{i=1}^{n}i\cos{x_{i}})^2$

Comment: I did some simulation. It seems $\{x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n\}=\{0, \pi\}$ at optimum.

Comment: @inequality I wrote the question logically, emphasizing that $n$ is fixed, and $x_1,\dots,x_n$ is the stuff we optimize over.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I think it's $ke^{ix_k}$ instead of $ke^{ikx_k}$.

Comment: For the special case $n=2$, we can put $x_1=0$ and $x_2=\pi$ which yields $F=-2$.  When $n=2$, the given sum has only one term, with the factor $ij = 1 \cdot 2= 2$ and the factor $\cos(x_i - x_j)$ achieves its minimum value of $-1$.

For larger values of $n$, the given sum has ${n \choose 2}$ terms.  If we put 
$ \displaystyle  S_n := \sum_{1 \leq i<j \leq n}^n ij,  \quad$ then the given sum will be bounded by $\pm S$.  That is,
$$-S_n \leq \sum_{1 \leq i<j \leq n}^n ij\underset{w_{ij} \, \in \, [-1,1]}{\underbrace{\cos(x_i - x_j)}} \leq S_n.  $$

Comment: Additionally, from a topological standpoint $F$ is a continuous function from a compact space to the reals (i.e. $F: [0,\pi]^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$).  Therefore, by the Extreme Value Theorem, $F$ achieves its maximum and minimum values at some points in its domain.  (It is clear that the maximum value, $S_n$, occurs at every point on the diagonal (i.e. when $x_1=x_2= \cdots = x_n = c \in [0, \pi]$).  It is not so clear where the minimum value is achieved.)

Comment: @SelrachDunbar thanks. good comments

Answer (score 2):

Let us minimize the OP expression
$$2F = \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\sin x_i\right)^2 + \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\cos x_i\right)^2 - \sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2.\tag1$$
The stationary points of *F* can be defined from the system
$$\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x_j}=0,\quad j=1,2,\dots,n,$$
or
$$j\cos x_j\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\sin x_i\right) - j\sin x_j\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i\cos x_i\right) =0,\quad j=1,2,\dots,n,\tag2$$
with the solutions in the forms of

- $\sin x_1 =\sin x_2 = \dots = \sin x_n =0,\; F =0,\;$ and
- $\cos x_1=\cos x_2=\dots=\cos x_n=0.$

Since $\;0\le x_1\le x_2\le \dots\le x_n\le \pi,\;$ then in the second case there are $\;(n+1)\;$ stationary points with the first *k* zero unknowns, or
$$x^{(k)}_i = \pi \theta(i-k-\,^1\!/_2),\quad k=0,1,\dots n,\tag3$$
$$2F_k = \left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^k i -\sum\limits_{i=k+1}^n i\right)^2-\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6,\tag4$$
where $\;\theta(t)\;$ is the Heaviside's step function.

At the same time,
$$d_k=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{k} i - \sum\limits_{i=k+1}^{n} i = \dfrac12(k^2+k-(n-k)(n+k+1)) = k^2+k-\dfrac{n^2+n}2,\tag5$$
and then from $(4)$ should
$$\min\limits_k F_k = F_{m},\quad\text{where}\quad d_{\large m\pm1}^2 \ge d_{\large m}^2. \tag6$$
Thus,
\begin{cases}
(2m^2-2m-n^2-n)^2 - (2m^2+2m-n^2-n)^2 \ge0\\[4pt]
(2m^2+6m+4-n^2-n)^2 - (2m^2+2m-n^2-n)^2 \ge0,
\end{cases}
\begin{cases}
2m^2\le n^2+n\\[4pt]
2(m+1)^2\ge n^2+n,
\end{cases}
and finally
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{\min F = \dfrac18(2m^2+2m-n^2-n)^2 -\dfrac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{12},}}\tag7$$
where
$$\color{green}{\mathbf{m=\left\lfloor\sqrt{\dfrac{n^2+n}2}\;\right\rfloor.}} \tag8$$
[image: Table for i=2 to 11]

Answer (score 1):

**This is not a full answer and contains errors (see comments) but I have left it up in case some of the ideas are useful to other users.**

The derivative of $\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}ij\cos(x_i-x_j)$ with respect to any chosen $x_i$  is $-i\sum_{j\ne i}j\sin(x_i-x_j)$.
 This derivative must equal $0$ at any local minima.

$\sin(x_i-x_j)$ is strictly positive unless $x_i$ and $x_j$ are both in $\{0,\pi\}$. This proves River Li's  comment.

Let  $\sigma(i)=\begin{cases}  1 \ \text{ if } x_i=0\\ -1 \text{ if } x_i=\pi \end{cases}$ so that

$\sum_{1\leq i<j\leq n}ij\cos(x_i-x_j)=\sum_{1\leq i<j \leq n}ij\sigma(i)\sigma(j)$.

The next step is to rewrite $\sum_{1\leq i<j \leq n}ij\sigma(i)\sigma(j)=\frac{1}{2}\left( \sum_{1\leq i\leq n}\sum_{1\leq j\leq n} ij\sigma(i)\sigma(j)-\sum_{1\leq i\leq n} i^2\sigma(i)\sigma(i) \right)=\frac{1}{2}\left(\left(\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}i\sigma(i)\right)^2-\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}i^2\right)$.

It is well known that $\sum_{1\leq i \leq n}i^2=\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}$.

All that remains is to minimise $\left(\sum_i i\sigma(i)\right)^2$. The condition $x_1\leq x_2 \leq ...$ means that there is a $k$ such that $\sigma(i)=1$ for $i\leq k$ and $\sigma(i)=-1$ for $i>k$. So we need to  minimise  $\left|\sum_i i\sigma(i)\right|=\left|2\binom{k+1}{2}-\binom{n+1}{2}\right|$.

Comment: Great solution!  One (minor) edit.  Note that $0 \leq x_i \leq x_j \leq \pi$ means that $-\pi \leq x_i - x_j \leq 0$.  So $-\sin(x_i - x_j)$ is strictly positive unless $x_i=x_j$ or both $x_i$ and $x_j$ are in $\{0, \pi\}$.  Maximums occur where $x_i=x_j$.  The rest follows as @AngelaRichardson has described.  Thanks!

Comment: "This derivative must equal 0 at any local minima" (с) It is not true for constrained optimization. For example, consider $\min_{x\in[0,1]} x$. The local/global min is at $x=0$, but the derivative is not zero there.

Comment: Unfortunately, after thinking about this a bit more, I have come to realize we were a bit hasty in calculating the formula for the partial with respect to $x_k$.  In fact,

$$ \displaystyle  D_{x_k}F = \sum_{1 \leq i < k} ik \sin(x_i - x_k) - \sum_{k < j \leq n} kj \sin(x_k - x_j),$$

the difference of two negative quantities for the given domain/conditions on the $x_i$.

Comment: If $n=5$ and we set $F_3(x):= (D_{x_3}F)(x_1,x_2,x,x_4,x_5)$ and put $x_1=0, x_2=1, x_3=x, x_4=3, x_5=\pi$, the graph https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ogcyxcg7bv shows there is some $x \in (1,3)$ for which $F_3(x)=0$.

Comment: Even with just $n=3$ there is another point, $(1, \approx 2.81, \pi)$, at which the partial with respect to $x_2$ is $0$ ... https://www.desmos.com/calculator/oh11uedp63